# Trying to understand lambda calculus substitution rules w.r.t. to free and bound variables?

Tags: substitution, python, lambda-calculus

[The Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://iep.utm.edu/lambda-calculi/#SH2b) defines bound and free variables in lambda calculus as:

> In a term $λx.P$, $x$ is a bound variable, as are similarly bound variables in the subterm $P$; variables which are not bound are free.

It also says about substitution in lambda calculus:

> We can then define the substitution of $N$ for $x$ in term $M$, denoted $M[x
> > := N]$, as follows:
>
> 1. $x[x := N] = N$
> 2. $y[x := N] = y$ (provided that $x$ is a variable different
>    than $y$)
> 3. $(PQ)[x := N] = P[x := N]Q[x := N]$
> 4. $(λx.P)[x := N] = λx.P$
> 5. $(λy.P)[x := N] = λy.P[x := N]$ (provided that $x$ is different than $y$ and $y$ is not free in $N$ or $x$ is not free in $P$)

I understand `1.`, `2.` and `3.`, but don't quite understand `4.` and `5.`

---

*Re: `4.` $(λx.P)[x := N] = λx.P$:*

In `4.`, we have $M[x:=N]$ where $M=\lambda x.P$, so would we say $x$ is a bound variable in $M$ or in $P$ or both? Why does the fact that $x$ is bound preclude us from substituting $N$ for $x$ in $P$? i.e. why isn't $(λx.P)[x := N]$ not equal to $λx.(P[x:=N])$? If an example, would help explain this better, please provide an example.

Can this be understand from a programming perspective? How would we encode $(λx.P)$ in Python for example? As `M = lambda x: P` or `M = lambda x: P(x)`? And if it is possible to encode $(λx.P)$ as either, what effect does the substitution step (i.e. $[x:=N]$ have on the code?

---

*Re: `5.` $(λy.P)[x := N] = λy.P[x := N]$ (provided that $x$ is different than $y$ and $y$ is not free in $N$ or $x$ is not free in $P$):*

Why are the *"$y$ is not free in $N$"* and *"$x$ is not free in $P$"* restrictions imposed?

Again, can this be understand from a programming perspective? How would we encode $(λy.P)$ in Python for example? As `M = lambda y: P` or `M = lambda y: P(y)`? And if it is possible to encode $(λy.P)$ as either, what effect does the substitution step (i.e. $[x:=N]$ have on the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gist for your answer is already in your same reference just below your quoted section:

> Intuitively, these substitution rules allow us to replace all the free occurrences of a variable (x) with any term (N). We cannot replace the bound occurrences of the variable (or allow for a variable to become bound by a substitution, as accounted for in the last rule) because that would change the “meaning” of the term.

So your rule 4. is dealing with bound occurrence of $x$ which cannot be replaced by any term $N$, and this applies to either of your python code. Your first python code expresses a constant function with value P (note in python programing to avoid runtime error P needs to be a fixed value term, not any symbol), and your second code express a normal lambda function of $x$.

Re: 5. if $y$ is free in $N$, then you can still substitute $N$ for $x$ in $P$, but you have to rename your bound variable $y$ *additionally* to keep valid, otherwise its meaning changed. You can easily think of a simple example to verify this...

Comment: could you walk me through applying `5.` when $N = λy.y$ and $P = λx.x$ which I believe meets all three restrictions of `5.`. I get to $λy.(λx.x)[x := (λy.y)]$, but not sure how to proceed from there because one of the substitutions is to the variable $x$ that follows a $λ$, which is an invalid step (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4303277/in-lambda-calculus-the-%ce%bb-symbol-is-followed-by-a-variable-can-that-variable-be/4303312#4303312)

Comment: @joseville yes you can first arrive at $λy.P=λy.(λx.x)$ per rule 5. But then to substitute $N$ for $x$ while $N=λy.y$ you need to invoke rule 4 since here the occurrence of $x$ is bound. Per rule 4 discussed above, you cannot really substitute a bound variable occurrence, so you're stuck to remain at $λy.(λx.x)=λyx.x$ of type $y \to x \to x$.

Answer (score -1):

A. We define free-variable/bound-variable as a function which associate to each lambda term its set of (free variables)/(bound variables).
The definition is done by induction and a variable can simultaneously be both bound and free in a given lambda term.
The dictionary definition is outdated and inadequate.

B. Point "5." adds unnecessary conditions meant for non capture of free variables (y not free in N). I suggest you remove that condition. Then you will have a substitution fonction (with capture of free variables). There is a way to naturally define capture avoiding substitution which uses a little bit of bound-variable renaming. But non capture avoiding substitution is also very conceptually important.