# Is this $\beta$-reduction step incorrect or not?

Tags: lambda-calculus

The brilliant.org article on Lambda Calculus$^1$ says that the following $\beta$-reduction step is incorrect:

\begin{align}
& (\lambda x.\lambda y.(xy))(\lambda x.\lambda y.(xy)) \\
& \rightarrow^\beta (\lambda y.((\lambda x.\lambda y.(xy))y))
\end{align}

because it leads to the wrong result:

$$\lambda y.\lambda y.(yy)$$

I don't think the $\beta$-reduction step itself is incorrect, but the subsequent one has to be done carefully so as not to capture a free variable:

\begin{align}
& (\lambda x.\lambda y.(xy))(\lambda x.\lambda y.(xy)) \\
& \rightarrow^\beta (\lambda y.((\lambda x.\lambda y.(xy))y)) \\
& \rightarrow^\alpha (\lambda y'.((\lambda x.\lambda y.(xy))y')) \\
& \rightarrow^\beta \lambda y'.\lambda y.y'y
\end{align}

Or, as noted by @mohottnad, if strictly following the rules of substitution stated in the brilliant.org article$^2$, the $\alpha$-conversion should rename the innermost bound $y$, not the outermost. In that case, we have:

\begin{align}
& (\lambda x.\lambda y.(xy))(\lambda x.\lambda y.(xy)) \\
& \rightarrow^\beta (\lambda y.((\lambda x.\lambda y.(xy))y)) \\
& \rightarrow^\alpha (\lambda y.((\lambda x.\lambda y'.(xy'))y)) \\
& \rightarrow^\beta \lambda y.\lambda y'.yy'
\end{align}

---

$^1$: [https://brilliant.org/wiki/lambda-calculus/#:~:text=x%20y)%5Cbig)-,(%CE%BBx.%CE%BBy.(xy))(%CE%BBx.%CE%BBy.(xy)),-Our%20first%20step](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lambda-calculus/#:%7E:text=x%20y)%5Cbig)-,(%CE%BBx.%CE%BBy.(xy))(%CE%BBx.%CE%BBy.(xy)),-Our%20first%20step)

$^2$: [https://brilliant.org/wiki/lambda-calculus/#:~:text=Let%20us%20formalize%20this%20with%20the%20notion%20of%20(capture%2Davoiding)%20substitution%20of%20free%20variables.](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lambda-calculus/#:%7E:text=Let%20us%20formalize%20this%20with%20the%20notion%20of%20(capture%2Davoiding)%20substitution%20of%20free%20variables.)

---

EDIT: to elaborate further, here are some annotations showing the binding of each variable in the original expression and after the first $\beta$-reduction: [annotations](https://q.uiver.app/?q=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)

Comment: There are two ways of formalising $\beta$-reduction. The first is that you can’t do it at all if it results in capture, so you must do an $\alpha$-conversion first. The second is that part of the $\beta$-reduction process involves substituting variables when capture could occur.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think the original $\beta$-reductions results in capture though. See annotations in my latests edit.

Comment: I agree with you that the given step is correct; the last occurrence of $y$ in the resulting expression is outside the scope of the inner $\lambda y$, so it's not captured. It's the subsequent $\beta$-reduction step that would give the incorrect result.

Comment: @joseville There are technically two $\beta$-reductions happening. The first, $(\lambda x . \lambda y . xy)\lambda x . \lambda y . xy \to_\beta \lambda y . (\lambda x . \lambda y . xy) y$, is legitimate. What is not legitimate is the second $\beta$-reduction, $(\lambda x . \lambda y . xy) y \to_\beta \lambda y . yy$. So you are correct that the flaw is in the second reduction. Whether you need to do an $\alpha$-conversion first or do the $\alpha$-conversion as part of the $\beta$-reduction step is a matter of convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're rightfully nitpicking here and the author in your reference described this edge case of $\beta$ conversion a little confusingly than necessary. You just need to follow rule 5 in one of your earlier [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4303415/trying-to-understand-lambda-calculus-substitution-rules-w-r-t-to-free-and-bound). Your above $\alpha$ conversion step is necessary since rule 5 doesn't apply ($y$ is obviously free in $N=y$!). So there's another rule which appears as the last rule of capture-avoiding substitution of $N$ for free occurrences of $x$ right under your quote in your reference.

Comment: Thanks! It is a nit for sure. I left some feedback in the article with link to this post.

Comment: @joseville if one strictly follows the last rule of your above brilliant.org article dealing with this edge case, actually the article should rename the innermost y to y' (should swap the position of the prime by mechanically following the substitution rules).

Comment: Good catch. I updated the question.